# How do I see settings afterwards on my Nikon D5100?

Tags: nikon, metadata, iso, shutter-speed, camera-settings

I am quite new to DSLR photography. What I can't figure out is how to see the settings for the photo after I have taken it.

For example, if I take a photo with 1/200, f5,6 and ISO 200. Can I see it afterwards or do I have to remember it?

Or another example. If I take a good shot in P-mode and I want to analyse what settings I had. How could I figure it out? It would be good for learning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you take a picture, the settings you used are stored inside the image file as EXIF metadata. Most photography software will allow you view this data in post (in fact, even Windows Explorer in Windows 7 can show it, by right-clicking the image and selecting "Properties" -> Details tab). You can also review the settings used to shoot images right on the camera during image review by pressing "up" - see page 26 of [the Nikon D5100 manual](http://www.nikonusa.com/pdf/manuals/dslr/D5100_EN.pdf).

When shooting, the camera can also show you what settings it's automatically selected at any given moment on the LCD display by pressing the "i" button (see page 28 of the manual).

Comment: I had some troubles making it work. But then I went in to menu>Playback meny>Playback display options. When there I checked the Overview checkbox. After that it worked

Answer (score 4):

After you have taken the picture, just press the play button and then the up button. Depending on how many times you press it, you will be able to see the exif, histogram etc.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I had enabled the options in the Play back Options, but still was not able to view the options while using the play button.